# How to make A-scale Bansuri blend into A-scale Tampura

Tags: scales, bansuri, tanpura

I have A scale Bass Bansuri 6 holes, total length is 23.5", length from embouchure (blowing hole) to Pa (6th and last hole) is 16"

I use online Tanpura, https://www.anubodh.com/tanpura.php  while practicing.

Somehow my Bansuri does not blend into the A scale

What can I be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: The measurements are about right for a bansuri with Sa=A (this is what Westerners would call an E bansuri, because that's the Pa). But maybe it's a bit out of tune, or you're playing out of tune,  which is why you need to check the intonation (see my first comment).

Comment: Since software recommendations are off-topic, this is only a comment: There are other virtual tanpura applications that include fine-tuning so you can adapt to the tuning of your bansuri.